# syntax error before ';' token

Tags: c, syntax-error

I wrote a quick program (Calculating wages) to help me stay up to speed. For some reason when I compile this I keep getting the error "53: syntax error before ';' token"

`#include`

```
int main()
{
#define week 7;
#define year 365;
int jan,feb,mar,apr,may,june,july,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec;
int wage;   /* Upgrade to float in future */
char input,month;

int holder;

jan=mar=may=july=aug=oct=dec=31;
apr=june=sep=nov=30;
feb=28;

for(;;)
{
    if(input='y')
    {
        #define YEAR 366;
        break;
    }
    else if(input='n')
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unable to understand input");
    }
}

printf("Enter wage/day in pounds.\n?\n");
scanf("%d",&wage);      /* unsure if I need to get string and then use atoi */
printf("Wage per day:\t%d\n",wage);
printf("Wage per week:\t%d\n",wage*7);
printf("Wage per month:\t%d\n",wage*30);

holder=YEAR;
printf("Wage per year:\t%d\n",wage*holder);
printf("As months have varying day amounts, if you wish to view a specific month type:\n");
printf("A-Jan\nB-Feb\nC-Mar\nD-Apr\nE-May\nF-June\nG-July\nH-Aug\nI-Sep\nJ-Oct\nK-Nov\nL-Dec\nor type X-to EXIT");

month=getchar();

if((month=='A')||(month=='C')||(month=='E')||(month=='G')||(month=='H')||(month=='J')||(month=='L')){
    printf("Wage for this month will be:\t%d",wage*31);
}
else if((month=='D')||(month=='F')||(month=='I')||(month=='K')){
    printf("Wage for this month will be:\t%d",wage*30);
}
else if((month=='B')&&(year==365)){
    printf("Wage for this month will be:\t%d",wage*28);
}
else if((month=='B')&&(year==366)){
    printf("Wage for this month will be:\t%d",wage*29);
}
else if(month=='X'){
    exit(1);
}
return 0;
```

}

No matter how many times I read through it I just can't manage to see what I'm doing incorrectly.

As a side note, if anybody feels like screaming/giving pointers about my style go ahead as I appreciate any tips that can lead to the improvement of my skills.

Thanks everyone, that was an overwhelmingly fast response, I've got the code compiled correctly so now I can start debugging the runtime errors (Before anyone mentions it. Yes I do understand the need to flush after input)

Comment: `if(month=='A'||'C'||'E'||'G'||'H'||'J'||'L'){` you can't do that.

Comment: if((month=='A')||(month=='B')||...)

Comment: There no `;` token on like 53. There must be something you are not showing us. Did you by any chance define `year` as a macro???

Comment: First off, exit(1) instead of exit 1

Comment: Wow, that was quick, I added the extra ()'s and almost feel like a complete moron for overlooking something so simple, but I'm still getting the error for some reason. @AndreyT Yes I have defined year as 365.

Comment: The chained || will compile, but won't give the desired effect.  You need to check each one.  See answers above/below.

Comment: `exit(1)` is normally used to indicate an error, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Show us the declaration of `year`. This is probably where the error lies since it's the only thing that's introduced at line 53.

Comment: @user3038224: Show us the exact definition of `year`. What is "I have defined year as 365" supposed to mean?

Comment: Did you by any chance define it as `#define year 365;` with a trailing semicolon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sintax is wrong, the correct way to write that is:

```
if((month=='A')||(month=='C')||(month=='E')||(month=='G')||(month=='H')||(month=='J')||(month=='L')){
printf("Wage for this month will be:\t%d",wage*31);
}
```

and so on. But you may want to consider the switch which is probably more easy to read.

```
switch( month ) {
   case 'A':
   case 'C':
   case 'E':
   case 'G':
   case 'H':
     printf( "statement A\n");
     break;
   case 'K':
   case 'D':
   case 'F':
     printf( "statement B\n");
      break;
   case 'B':
     if( year == 365) {
       printf( "something else\n" );
     } else if( year == 366 ) {
       printf( "something else\n" );
     } else {
       printf( "Unexpected year %d\n", year );
     }
     break;
   case 'X':
     return -1; /* Note here return... not exit! */
   default:
      printf( "Why am I here?\n" );
      break;
}
```

Now that you edited another error is `#define YEAR 365;`
Get rid of that ';'. You may prefer defining that as `int` instead of using a precompiler define, expecially **if you are going to change its value**

Answer (score 4):

One error (though not the one that immediately got you, it seems) is this line:

```
exit 1;
```

In C, `exit` is a regular function, and so you have to call it like this:

```
exit(1);
```

As others have pointed out, your use of `||` is also incorrect, though that is probably giving you warnings (if anything) and not errors.

Comment: You are correct about the syntax for calling `exit`, but according to the OP, the compiler is throwing an error much earlier than this code.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do

```
if (month=='A'||'C'||'E'||'G'||'H'||'J'||'L'){
    ... 
}
```

This way `month=='A'||'C'||'E'||'G'||'H'||'J'||'L'` you are comparing the wrong values, i.e. `<bool> || <char> || <char> ||...`, which gives you an invalid syntax.

Try this instead,

```
if (month=='A' ||
    month=='C' ||
    month=='E' || 
    month=='G' ||
    month=='H' ||
    month=='J' ||
    month=='L') {
    ... 
}
```

However, as mentioned by @danfuzz, the issue seems to lie elsewhere...

Answer (score 2):

There are many catastrophic problems with your code, but most of them (besides the `exit 1` bit) are formally compilable. They're just not doing what you think they're doing.

However, you state that you get a compilation error well before that `exit 1` line. If that is the case, then it must be caused by something you aren't showing us, since there's no `;` on line 53. My guess would be that `year` is defined as a macro that contains `;`.

**EDIT:** In the comments you said that you have defined `year` as `365`. I suspect that you did this

```
#define year 365;
```

This is what's causing the error. Get rid of that `;` after `365`. However, if that's the case I still don't get why you would compare your `year` to `365` or `366` if you already defined it to be `365` specifically.

**EDIT:** So, it is exactly as I guessed. You don't need those `;` after `#define` statements for manifest constants. This is your error. Macros are replaced by textual substitution meaning that currently your

```
if((month=='B')&&(year==365)){
```

gets translated into

```
if((month=='B')&&(365;==365)){
```

which is what causes the original error. If you want to define `year` as a macro constant that stands for `365`, it should be

```
#define year 365
```

The same applies to `week`, although you are not using it anywhere in your code.